# Convert Format-Hex PowerShell table to raw hex dump

Tags: powershell, hex, dump

I used the `Format-Hex` command in PowerShell to get the hex contents of a string. My command `"some_string" | format-hex` gives me the output in a table. How can I make it into a raw hex dump so it's something like `736f6d655f737472696e67`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Expand the `Bytes` property of the resulting object, format each byte as a double-digit hex number, then join them:

```
("some_string" | Format-Hex | Select-Object -Expand Bytes | ForEach-Object { '{0:x2}' -f $_ }) -join ''
```

However, it'd probably be simpler and more straightforward to write a custom function to converts a string to a hex representation:

```
function ConvertTo-Hex {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            Position=0,
            Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
        )]
        [string]$InputObject
    )

    $hex = [char[]]$InputObject |
           ForEach-Object { '{0:x2}' -f [int]$_ }

    if ($hex -ne $null) {
        return (-join $hex)
    }
}

"some_string" | ConvertTo-Hex
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and works perfectly! I will take note of the simpler function you wrote about too. Thanks!

Comment: @TamusJRoyce `{0:x2}` -> `{0:X2}` if you're referring to the code in my answer. Otherwise please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Format-Hex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-hex?view=powershell-7.4):

```
(('Hello World' | Format-Hex).HexBytes).Replace(' ','')
48656C6C6F20576F726C64
```